# Creating a Service that checks constant for Updates

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service, broadcast

Im new to this Community, but i frequently looked up my questions at this place for ages, and have never been disappointed! But this time I struggle to find the perfect Way/Answer/Solution to my Problem, so for the very first time i´ll have to ask on my own.

Im Creating a Game like Quizduell, it runs smooth and I have played it for many rounds with some friends. The only thing that does not work ist the "Check for Update and Notify me if there are some, from boot till shutdown" part of the App.

I have a Server running all the Time in the Internet. The Client, an Androidservice should request on the Server if there are News, the application sends the SessionID and the ID of the Player to the Server and gets back only a Name (to keep the Dataconsumption small). The Service gets the ID and the SessionID by SharedPreferences, because i had some struggles with the Intents. The Service now shows a Notification, this part works just fine. There is no Connection to the App, it runs completly on his own(Besides the SharedPreferences)

The Problem is, I just dont know how to get things started:

I have a Broadcast, which should fire at Boot (but im not shure if it does, i tested it with the Airplanemodechange and it fired, but only if the Application runs, and this is not what i want) It starts an AlarmManager who fires the Service every now and then:

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Process = ":remote", Name = "Broadcasts.UpdateBroadcast")]
[IntentFilter(new[] {  Intent.ActionBootCompleted, Intent.ActionAirplaneModeChanged})]
public class UpdateBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver
{

public static readonly String TAG = "com.JonQse.Schlauweia.UpdateBroadcast";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

        var updateService = new Intent(context, typeof(UpdateService));
        //context.StartService(updateService);
        PendingIntent _mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, updateService, 0);
        var am = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        long interval = 1000 * (int)(60 * 0.2);
        am.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + interval, interval, _mAlarmSender);

    }
}
```

So this just does not work at all. I have no Clue why. The next thing is, that i just cant fire the Broadcast manualy when I start the App, so that it at least runs:

```
            bool alarmUp = (PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0,
    new Intent(this, typeof(UpdateService)),
    PendingIntentFlags.NoCreate) != null);

        if(!alarmUp)
        {
            var intent = new Intent("Broadcasts.UpdateBroadcast");
            SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
```

I hope you can help me. I wouldnt write here if i woudlnt have gone Crazy about this Problem.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for my app.
Allow boot complete receiver in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Your function should look like this

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
    public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
            {
                context.StartService(new Intent(context, typeof(YourService)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside your service in

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
```

start the task Task.Run. Do your stuff in this task. Make sure you stop it when service destroyed. You can create a variable in your service "done" and check it in your task loop. If you don't need a task with loop you can start alarm manager in OnStartCommand too. If you don't need a separate service then just use the boot receiver definition as specified and it should fire all the time